# Path to a resource inside a jar executable

Tags: java, jar

I am using a Jasper library to make calls to a prolog file. This is how the call is done:

```
sics = new SICStus();
sics.load( "/a/string/with/path/to/source.pl" );
```

What i am trying to do is generate a jar executable that contains the source file. The problem is that i can't find a way to get the path to the resource contained within the jar. So far i am able to get the URL to the jar:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource( file_name );
String path = url.getPath();
```

The question is how do i give the object *"sics"* the path to the source file *source.pl* within the jar?

What made me understand the problem :

> Files in java can only represent direct filesystem files, not the ones
>   in zip/jar archives.
>   To fix it:
>   Try to use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` and use that instead of `File`.

**Link:** [URI is not hierarchical exception when running application from JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564312/uri-is-not-hierarchical-exception-when-running-application-from-jar)

Answer (score 2):

Guess this question is already answered if I do not misunderstand you request. Please take a look here: [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file?rq=1) or here [How to get a path to a resource in a Java JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file) and here [Loading a file relative to the executing jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627426/loading-a-file-relative-to-the-executing-jar-file).

Comment: Yes, i have seen all those posts, have tried all the options they gave. It might be my fault, but i find those answers either trying to go around the problem or simply not clear enough.